# Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin.login() failed: unrecognized authentication provider

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

Okay, I'm having a rather weird error. I'm setting up social login in my app with `facebook`,`twitter` and `google` with angularjs with a firebase backend. Both `facebook` and `twitter` login works find but not with google. Clicking the login with Google button throws this error on my console

`Error: FirebaseSimpleLogin.login() failed: unrecognized authentication provider`

This is rather weird and I'm not sure where the problem is

I have this in my views

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-facebook-inversed rounded" ng-click="login('facebook')">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
</button>
<button class="btn btn-block btn-googleplus-inversed rounded" ng-click="login('google')">
  <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Google+
</button>
<button class="btn btn-block btn-twitter-inversed rounded" ng-click="login('twitter')">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
</button>
```

In my sign-in controller

```
$scope.login = function(provider){
  loginService.loginWith(provider, function(err,user){
    if(err){
      $scope.err = "Unable to authenticate you via " + provider;
    } else {
      // write user details to firebase
    }

  });
}
```

And my loginService has this

```
loginWith: function(provider, callback){
  auth.$login(provider, {
    rememberMe: true
  }).then(function(user){
    callback && callback(null, user)
  },callback);
}
```

Twitter and Facebook authentications work fine but not with Google. What I'm I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the error message produced when you log in using Google, and version info.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are using the latest versions (as of this answer) of Firebase (1.0.17), AngularFire (0.7.1), and Simple Login (1.6.1).
2. Make sure you have Google authentication enabled in your Firebase dashboard with correct app credentials.
3. Make sure the string "google" is being passed to `$login()`.

If I had to bet, you are probably using an old version of our Simple Login client.

Answer (score 0):

If you use yeoman to generate project's seed remember to update bower.json file - it contains old libraries by default.

Check out this ticket on GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire/issues/22